# What is the work around for a weird javascript form submit bug in Safari 5?

Tags: javascript, safari

I am not sure if this is an existing bug, but after debugging a web application I am working on, I have discovered some weird behavior in Safari 5. Here is the scenario:

Page A ---- HTTP POST ----> Page B ---- HTTP POST ----> Page C

**Page A:**

```
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
        <form method="post" action="pageB.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="display" value="ABC" />
        </form>
</body>
```

**Page B:**

```
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
        <form method="post" action="pageC.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="display" value="123" />
                <input type="hidden" name="extra" value="XXX" />
        </form>
</body>
```

**Page C:**

```
<body>
<?php

        print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
</body>
```

Of all the browsers I have tested so far only Safari 5 (Mac version) will display the value "ABC" for name="display" and I still can see the value "XXX" for the field "extra". All other browsers (Including Safari 3, 4) will display the value "123" which is the correct value.

For some reasons I still need to submit the form using  for Page A and Page B, with this condition, what is the workaround for Safari 5? (To make it submit the correct value at Page B, which should be 123 instead of sort like forwarding the value from Page A to Page C)

Many Thanks!

- Edit1: Only happens on Mac OS (Snow Leopard, Lion) Safari 5
- Edit2: Make example more clear

Comment: Are the URLs actually the same for page a and b?

Comment: Yes, the URL is the same for page a and b, but even when I break it down in simulation like the examples above, the problem persists. (where page a and page b are of different URL)

Comment: OS platform? You tested this only in Safari? Other browsers FF, Chrome, Opera, IE?

Comment: Tested with FF (both Mac & Windows), Chrome (both Mac & Windows), IE (8,9), Safari 3, 4, 5 (Mac)

Comment: For Mac OS, also tested both with Snow Leopard & Lion

Comment: I cannot test on Mac. On my Win Safari 5 works as expected. Maybe you have cached _"pageA"_ on Safari 5 where _"pageA"_ sends request directly into _"pageC"_?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test, it seems like it only happens at Mac Safari 5. Yes, I have remembered to clear cache..

Comment: In which exact version did you encounter this? I couldn't get that unexpected result in Safari (mac) 5.0 and 5.1.6

Comment: I don't have a mac, so what happens if you perform the submit on document ready event?

Comment: Tested on Macbook Pro (Lion) + Safari 5.1.7 -> no problem

Comment: Yea, after I have updated to 5.1.7 few days ago the problem is gone

Comment: to : inhan, I wasn't sure which version I was on prior to 5.1.7 update, but I have tested on several machines before doing the recent Safari update and got the problem.

Comment: to : ramesh, I have tried with jQuery document ready or similar but the problem persists. But after the recent update to Safari 5.1.7 the problem is gone.

Answer (score 4):

Safari is filling in the form field using [autofill behaviour](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-applications-and-services/9781615420957/use-autofill-for-forms-and-passwords/use_autofill_for_forms_and_passwords). You probably have the "Other forms" option enabled in your preferences. Even Apple recommend you turn this feature off since it can be used for stealing private information.

To workaround this for people who have it turned on anyway try `<form autocomplete="off">`

Answer (score 0):

Fire up a proxy like Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/ and watch the post data move between forms.  If it only happens on this one browser on this one machine, it seems more likely like a browser cache thing than a form post error.  What if you start at pageB?  What if you clear your cache first?

Comment: The problem is that it will only happen at Safari 5 (Mac), and have tested on several other macbooks.

Comment: To explain this further that it is not a cache issue is that when I submit an extra form field let say name="extra" value="xxx" from Page B, I still see value="ABC" for name="display" but I still get the new extra value at Page C.